# asp.net mvc search with page doesnt work?

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to get view with search and paging but when the search is ok but when I click on the next page link no any thing is displayed

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Browse()
{
   return View();     
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Browse(FormCollection formContent ,int? page)
{
     string cartype = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(formContent["Cartype"]) ? formContent  "Cartype"] : "";
     string SearchBox = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(formContent["searchbox"]) ? formContent["searchbox"] : "";
     DateTime toDate = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(formContent["toDate"]) ? DateTime.Parse(formContent["toDate"]) : DateTime.MaxValue;
     string Sort = formContent["sort"];

     mvc4advertismentEntities2 db = new mvc4advertismentEntities2();
     var result = AdvertFunObj.GetAdverts();

     switch (Sort)
     {
         case "":
             result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.CarType == cartype).ToList();
             break;
         case "price":
             result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.CarType == cartype).OrderByDescending(m =>      m.Price).ToList();
             break;
         case "date":
             result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.CarType == cartype).OrderByDescending(m => m.ExpirationDate).ToList();
             break;
         case "enginecapaity": result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.CarType == cartype).OrderByDescending(m => m.EngineCapacity).ToList();
             break;
     }

     int pageSize = 6;
     int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
     return View(result.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
 }
```

the view

```
 <table  class="advertbrowsediv " id="searcht" width="100%"><tr><td style="width: 42%">   فئة السياره    :
      <br />
                   <%: Html.DropDownList("Cartype", new SelectListItem [] {
                  new SelectListItem(){Text="مرسيدس",Value="مرسيدس", Selected=true},
               new SelectListItem(){Text="ميتسوبيشي",Value="ميتسوبيشي"},
      }) %>  
</td>

<td >ترتيب حسب : 
<br />
    <%: Html.DropDownList("sort", new SelectListItem [] {
             new SelectListItem(){Text="",Value="", Selected=true},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="التاريخ",Value="date"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="السعر",Value="price"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="سعة المحرك",Value="enginecapaity"},


},
</td><td><br /><input style=" float:right" type="submit" value="بحث>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not clear, anyway if you click on the next page link you are performing a get, not a post. So you should add logic to your get method.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the search you're using HttpPost method and  your method "Browse" gets executed where the searching and the paging is happening.

When you hit next page you will have HttpGet request (I presume) and whatever you're doing in "Browse (httpPost) is not going to happen.

Going to a new page will require you to preserve your search criteria, your page number and in that method you need to fetch again your dataset and do the paging. You can pass them as query parameters.

The other option that you have is to make your next page request to be HTTPPost request and make it execute "Browse" (httpPost)

Fiddler is your friend http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
Run it and you will see what exactly gets sent to the server, what verb is used, etc.

I hope that helps.